# How do i get a data out of a complex JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

> I have a JSON file below and im trying to get the "active_cases" result, but anytime i try to access it using ["rows"] i get an error, anyone with any idea how to get it?

```
{
"data": {
    "paginationMeta": {
        "currentPage": 1,
        "currentPageSize": 2,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "totalRecords": 2
    },
    "last_update": "May, 08 2020, 16:29, UTC",
    "rows": [
        {
            "country": "Netherlands",
            "country_abbreviation": "NL",
            "total_cases": "42,093",
            "new_cases": "319",
            "total_deaths": "5,359",
            "new_deaths": "71",
            "total_recovered": "N/A",
            "active_cases": "36,484",
            "serious_critical": "564",
            "cases_per_mill_pop": "2,457.0",
            "flag": "https://www.worldometers.info/img/flags/nl-flag.gif"
        },
        {
            "country": "Caribbean Netherlands",
            "country_abbreviation": "",
            "total_cases": "6",
            "new_cases": "0", 
            "total_deaths": "0", 
            "new_deaths": "0", 
            "total_recovered": "0",
            "active_cases": "6", 
            "serious_critical": "0", 
            "cases_per_mill_pop": "229.0", 
            "flag": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/International_Flag_of_Planet_Earth.svg/800px-International_Flag_of_Planet_Earth.svg.png"
        }
    ]
}, 
"status": "success"
```

}

Comment: Have you tried dict['data']['rows']? From there you can probably extract the 'active cases'.

Answer (score 0):

```
active_cases = []
for row in dict['data']['rows']:
    active_cases.append(row['active_cases'])
```

Comment: my row variable is this =  data = test.json() and the test is = test = requests.get(url)

Comment: When i tried ur solution i got an error stating "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 0):

The active cases are in  list that in the rows inside data so you can do

```
import json

json_obj = """{"data": {"paginationMeta": {"currentPage": 1, "currentPageSize": 2, "totalPages": 1, "totalRecords": 2}, "last_update": "May, 08 2020, 16:29, UTC", "rows": [{"country": "Netherlands", "country_abbreviation": "NL", "total_cases": "42,093", "new_cases": "319", "total_deaths": "5,359", "new_deaths": "71", "total_recovered": "N/A", "active_cases": "36,484", "serious_critical": "564", "cases_per_mill_pop": "2,457.0", "flag": "https://www.worldometers.info/img/flags/nl-flag.gif"}, {"country": "Caribbean Netherlands", "country_abbreviation": "", "total_cases": "6", "new_cases": "0", "total_deaths": "0", "new_deaths": "0", "total_recovered": "0", "active_cases": "6", "serious_critical": "0", "cases_per_mill_pop": "229.0", "flag": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/International_Flag_of_Planet_Earth.svg/800px-International_Flag_of_Planet_Earth.svg.png"}]}, "status": "success"}"""

print([i["active_cases"] for i in json.loads(json_obj)["data"]["rows"]])
```

That will print you the 2 numbers of active cases

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is what i received when I try it "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"

Answer (score 0):

You first load the json with the following:

```
import json
d = json.loads("""{"data": {"paginationMeta": {"currentPage": 1, "currentPageSize": 2, "totalPages": 1, "totalRecords": 2}, "last_update": "May, 08 2020, 16:29, UTC", "rows": [{"country": "Netherlands", "country_abbreviation": "NL", "total_cases": "42,093", "new_cases": "319", "total_deaths": "5,359", "new_deaths": "71", "total_recovered": "N/A", "active_cases": "36,484", "serious_critical": "564", "cases_per_mill_pop": "2,457.0", "flag": "https://www.worldometers.info/img/flags/nl-flag.gif"}, {"country": "Caribbean Netherlands", "country_abbreviation": "", "total_cases": "6", "new_cases": "0", "total_deaths": "0", "new_deaths": "0", "total_recovered": "0", "active_cases": "6", "serious_critical": "0", "cases_per_mill_pop": "229.0", "flag": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/International_Flag_of_Planet_Earth.svg/800px-International_Flag_of_Planet_Earth.svg.png"}]}, "status": "success"}""")
```

Then you can filter the json in the following way:

```
result = [item['active_cases'] for item in d['data']['rows']]
```